# How to dial USSD CODE by using button on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile

I am trying to dial a USSD Code using this code

```
<button onclick="document.location.href = 'tel:*556#'">Check balance</button>
```

but is not working on mobile

Comment: You probably can't do that.

Comment: but why do you vote me down i am only asking for help, common i don't ask for down vote i need help

Comment: Likely because there is not much of a description on the error, or any examples of things you have tried to resolve it, or research done on an explaination.

Comment: PHP is a server-side programming language and what you are trying to do is on the client side, you will use HTML and JS in this case

Answer (score 2):

You should rely on anchor tags for that since you want to open another app via a hyperlink.

Using the following should work for you

```
<a href="tel:*556%23">Check balance</a>
```

`%23` is the the url encoded value of `#`. The rule of thumb is to encode the url of your link (number). You can use `encodeURIComponent('your-number-here')` to do that